# More Issues with overlapping labels in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, label

I am  having a problem with Tkinter.  The issue is as follows.

I retrieve information from a Database. I wish to print that out based off a few user selections.
Sometimes I want to print out columns A, B, C
Sometimes I want to print out columns, A, B, C, D
Sometimes I want to print out columns A, B, D, E

Also, when I query, I do not know ahead of time how many results I will have. Some queries give 1.  Some give 200.  To print them, I do something like this...

```
            while x < results.num_rows() :
                result = results.fetch_row()
                author = result[0][0]
                title = result[0][1]
                conference = result[0][2]
                year = result[0][3]
                location = result[0][4]
                Label(root, text=title).grid(row=startRow,column=0,columnspan=5,sticky=W)
                Label(root,text=author).grid(row=startRow,column=6,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
                Label(root,text=year).grid(row=startRow,column=7,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
                Label(root,text=conference).grid(row=startRow,column=8,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
                Label(root,text=location).grid(row=startRow,column=9,columnspan=1,sticky=W)
                startRow+=1
                x+=1
```

This accomplishes what I want. I get a label printed below the previous for each item. It prints the desired columns (in this case, title, author, year, conference, location).  Sometimes its different. It's all good.

Until my user does another query.  I can't delete the previous labels. I have no reference to them. I can't make a reference to them, because I dont know ahead of time how many I will need.  The number of labels is based off of the query the user wants and obviously the matching entries in the database.

So when the user does the 2nd or 3rd query, results start to get printed on top of one another.

What can I do?

EDIT - This was the attempt.  I added in

```
    try :
        for item in labelList :
            item.grid_forget()
    except :
        pass
```

I put that at the beginning of my button code, so that if the labelList already exists,  it will do this at each query.  If it doesn't exist, it will just pass.

```
            while x < results.num_rows() :
                result = results.fetch_row()
                title = result[0][0]
                conference = result[0][1]
                year = result[0][2]
                location = result[0][3]
                message = title + "\t\t\t\t\t" + conference + "\t" + str(year) + "\t" + location
                label = Label(root, text=title)
                label.grid(row=startRow, column=0, columnspan=5,sticky=W)
                labelList.append(label)
                label = Label(root, text=conference)
                label.grid(row=startRow, column=6, columnspan=1,sticky=W)
                labelList.append( label )
                label = Label(root, text=year)
                label.grid(row=startRow, column=7, columnspan=1,sticky=W)
                labelList.append( label )
                label = Label(root, text=location)
                label.grid(row=startRow, column=8, columnspan=1,sticky=W)
                labelList.append( label )
                startRow+=1
                x+=1
```

However I am still getting the overlapping issue.

Comment: Keep a `list` of references to `Label`s?

Comment: Not sure how I would go about that.  Each label would have to have a unique name, no?  How would I generate that unique name on the fly?  I suppose I could do something like having a string

"label" and concatenate it with "x", my iteration number.  

Then store all of those in a list.  After each query, just cycle through the list and grid_forget() them.

Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, why do you think they have to have a unique name? Just `append` the object to the list; that can be the only reference to it.

Comment: note that when you store a reference to the label, make sure you call grid on a separate line or you'll just be storing a list of `None`s. (ie: `Label(...).grid(...)` always returns `None` because `.grid(...)` returns `None`)

Comment: I dont think I am fully understanding the explanation from jon. I will update the code with my attempt based off what my understanding was.

Comment: I would grid the data into a frame instead of directly into root.  Or look into using ttk.Treeview instead (if there are multiple search keys).  For a new query, create a new frame (or tree) and either destroy the old one.  For a later exercise, add old query results to a list of previous query results that a user can go back to. Or put each query result in a new tab of a ttk.Notebook.  PS. does '200 hundred' mean '200' or '20000'?

Comment: Was a typo. Fixed.  Hmm, I haven't used Tkinter much. I will have to try and look into using additional frames when I have time.  It's kind of mind-boggling how difficult it is to simply remove a label though. :/ Been at this for days and cannot get this overlapping to stop.

Comment: Removing a label is trivial: `the_label.destroy()` is all you need. You are making the problem harder than it is.

Comment: Perhaps I am, but I am failing to see how is the problem.  As I posted above, I have the code to destroy on each iteration of the button click before new labels are processed, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are ignoring errors in that try/catch block. Did you double-check that it's not throwing an error. Also, the code you show calls grid_forget rather than destroy -- this is a memory leak since you create dozens or hundreds of labels for each query but never destroy them.m

Comment: I have! Also, I can change them back to destroy as needed (I actually had an iteration doing that, but wanted to try forget to see if it changed anything)

The exception being thrown is that "local variable labelList' is referenced before assignment"

I expected that to happen on the first iteration. It hasn't been created yet.

The second and third though, I would expect it to exist, and thus delete.  Apparently not.

Comment: If it is a local variable, it gets destroyed each time the function exits.

Comment: Yup! I realized I was being dumb.  I made the list global and it works beautifully.

While I have your attention, can I ask a quick question (since you seem to pop up in all my search results anyway)

Once my query is done and it prints the 200 or so labels going down the screen, I can only see like 50 of them.  Is there a way to add a scrollbar to the MASTER frame? I don't want to have to create additional frames this far in.  I just want a scrollbar for my UI in general, if that makes sense.

Comment: Search this site. There are several examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of widgets, you can store the ID's in a list and destroy each one, or place them in a new frame and destroy the frame each time, which also removes the reference to the widget's in it.  Personally, I would reuse the labels for all of the results from one query, i.e. attach a textvariable to each one, then set the textvariable to the new value for each record found, or "" if it is empty.  See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm for info on the textvariable option for labels.

```
def next_set_of_recs():
    print "next set"
    old_frame.destroy()

top = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(top, text="not in created frame").grid()

old_frame=tk.Frame(top)
old_frame.grid(row=1)
tk.Label(old_frame, text="a_label", width=50).grid()
## give it some time, otherwise it is instantly destroyed
top.after(2000, next_set_of_recs)  

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why use textvariables? That doubles the number of objects but doesn't really buy you anything. It's a function call to update the textvariable, and it's a function call to reset the text on the label